# How to call 2 Future functions that return Future values in FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-bloc, flutter-futurebuilder

I am working on a complex web application in which from time to time, I need to fetch data from backend API. Sometimes, I need to call 2 future functions in Future Builder to use their values. However, it makes code messy because for each FutureBuilder I need to check, if it has data or not and return the widget. It looks like this.

```
return FutureBuilder<object>(
   future: func1(),
   builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<object> snapshot1){
      if(snapshot1.hasData){
        return FutureBuilder<object>(
        future: func2(),
        builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<object> snapshot2){
           if(snapshot2.hasData){
              return widget;
           }else{
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
      ),
      }else{
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
);
```

Is there any other simpler way? where I can use only one FutureBuilder so that I do not have to return widgets i.e (CircularProgressIndicator)each time. Thanks.

Comment: are these two future related to each other? can you add example with their future too?

Comment: No, they are not related but their return values I need to use in one function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create result model class like this:

```
class ResultModel{
  final object1 result1;
  final object2 result2;
  ResultModel({required this.result1, required this.result2});
}
```

then you can create new `future` like this:

```
Future<ResultModel> _newFuture() async {
  final results = await Future.wait([func1(), func2()]);
  return ResultModel(result1: results[0], result2: results[1]);
}
```

then pass this to single `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder<ResultModel>(
   future: _newFuture(),
   builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<ResultModel> snapshot1){
      if(snapshot1.hasData){
        return return widget;
      }else{
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: How can I use result1 and result2 in another function? I mean it I need to create another widget from these values.

Comment: I would optimize that code to use Future.wait() instead of sequentially awaiting func1 and func2. That could improve the waiting time significantly.

Comment: @RobertSandberg I tried Future.wait() but it takes a list.

Comment: @RobertSandberg fill free to edit the code. if it was not helpful I will rollback it,

Comment: Code edited. This will execute both func1 and func2 and wait until both are completed. Could split the wait time in about half, if both functions take equal time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate with ResultModel class as the accepted answer suggests. What if we need 3 futures to run? Create the new model for 3? And 4?

Simple solution is below. Note that you can use `List<dynamic>` if functions return different types, and you could cast accordingly when reading the value.

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
   future: Future.wait([func1(), func2()]),
   builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot1){
      if(snapshot1.hasData){
        var result1=snapshot1.data[0];
        var result1=snapshot1.data[1];
        return return widget;
      }else{
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: You are also using AsyncSnapshot<ResultModel>.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the code now.

Answer (score 0):

1/. If func1 and func2 are independent, you can call it same time by using

**Future.wait** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html

2/. If your func2 depend on func1. Write 1 custom func and use it in your future builder:

```
func1AndFunc2() async {
 var result = await func1();
 // check result has data
 if (result != null) {
    return func2();
 }
}
```